# I feel like my :colorscheme is not displayed correctly. There is so much terminology involved. What are vim color modes?

Tags: terminal, vim, colors

I have a feeling that the :colorschemes I'm using in Vim are not displayed properly.
**That the colors are corrupted.**
I think this because I have 3 virtual machines rented from 3 different vendors, two Ubuntu 22.04 systems and one Debian 12.
I have Vim installed on all of them, with minimal amount of plugins.

I guess on all 3 of them, I have the same settings:

- `slate` color scheme,
- `:set background=dark`,
- `syntax on`,
- `:set termguicolors? = notermguicolors`;

But this `slate` color scheme looks different on each and every VPS, that I connect to.

Like so, this is how `slate` looks on my terminal:

[image]

I guess `slate` should look like this, [here](https://vimcolorschemes.com/rainglow/vim):

[image]

this is how `desert` looks on my terminal:

[image]

I guess `desert` should look like this, [here](https://vimcolorschemes.com/vim-scripts/vim_colors):

[image]

I like these colors more from the [website](https://vimcolorschemes.com/), because the text is brighter and the contrast is just just on optimal level and on my computer, the text is to dimm / dark and the contrast is to low.
**And of course the colors are all corrupted, not just slightly shifted towards red or blue.**

I'm connecting to this VPS from my home laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, Gnome desktop.
I'm using Gnome Terminal, Version 3.44.0 for GNOME 42. Everything, both on my home laptop and on all my VPSes is all up to date, latest version available, updated, upgraded, rebooted twice a week. No important apps or processes there, which would make rebooting the machine an issue.

My biggest disappointment to date: the `gruvbox` Vim theme looks like this on my terminal:

[image]

And this is how this `gruvbox` color scheme [should look like](https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox/wiki/Gallery):

[image]

In other threads people where asking about `echo $TERM` output, so here it is:

```
michal@ubuntu:~$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

They where asking also about `echo $COLORTERM` but I have **empty string** from this one (is it good or bad, please explain. It's hard to find what `$COLORTERM` stands for.):

```
michal@ubuntu:~$ echo $COLORTERM
```

I've tried to enable `:set termguicolors`, but it only makes the colors more ugly, more random and adds some strange highlighting which only disturbs me.
This is how `colorscheme slate` looks like with `:set termguicolors` enabled:

[image]

This is how `colorscheme gruvbox` looks like with `:set termguicolors` enabled:

[image]

Looks very far from what the developer shows on the `gruvbox` print screens on his [github page](https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox/wiki/Gallery).

Here's the rest of the `~/.vimrc file`, that was not visible on the print screens:

```
syntax reset                " Reapply the syntax highlighting rules based on the current colorscheme and other related settings.
set nocompatible            " Set compatibility to Vim only.
"    ^%#@thousand:'   anne-marie-claire'claudia:B    boys-and-girls'*    james_bond_007'    '"stuff_is_so_good"'
set wildmenu                " Enable Vim's builtin auto completion engine
set ignorecase              " By default searching in Vim using / command is case-sensitive.
"                           " Use 'set ignorecase' to set searching in Vim case insensitive.
"                           " Use 'set smartcase' to make search case insensitive if you type
"the search pattern using lower case only.
"
set number                  " Show line numbers.  Opposite is set nonumber.
"
set shiftwidth=2            " Set tabulator size to 2
"                           " The amount of spaces the text shifts after >> key is pressed.
set tabstop=2               " Set tabulator size to 4
"                           " The amount of spaces the text shifts after Tab key is pressed.
set softtabstop=2           " Set tabulator size to 4
"                           " https://youtu.be/6sslhOEd2ZA?si=jAJ7Sio15a5UW_GB 
"
set wrap                    " Automatically wrap text that extends beyond the screen length.
"
set laststatus=2            " Show status bar.
set fileformat=unix         " This option is local to each buffer.
"
set encoding=utf-8          " Force encoding.
set list                    " Shows hidden characters
"set nolist                 " Hide invisible characters
set list                    " Shows hidden characters
"
set nohlsearch              " Disable search highlighting.
set hlsearch                " Enable search highlighting.
"
"                           " Call the .vimrc.plug file
if filereadable(expand("~/.vimrc.plug"))
  source /home/michal/.vimrc.plug
endif
"
"
"
" i  Insert mode map. Defined using ':imap' or ':inoremap'.
:inoremap <Caps> <Esc>
":inoremap <Caps_Lock> <Esc>
":inoremap <CapsLock> <Esc>
set t_u7=    "  https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/6365
"               https://superuser.com/questions/1284561/why-is-vim-starting-in-replace-mode
"
" Press F4 to toggle highlighting on/off, and show current value.
:noremap <F4> :set hlsearch! hlsearch?<CR>
"
filetype on
syntax on
```